# How to add datatype object to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to dynamically add datatype objects to a dictionary, in order to specify the 'dtype' argument in the pd.read_csv function.

The problem is that simply passing *'key' : str* or *'key' : float* to dict.update() does not preserve the datatype objects and has no effect on the dtype argument.

I have attempted the following:

```py
for column in list_of_columns:

    dict.update({column : str})
```

I expected to see something like:

```
{
'a' : str,
'b' : str,
'c' : str
}
```

But instead it produces:

```
{
'a' : <class 'str'>,
'b' : <class 'str'>,
'c' : <class 'str'>
}
```

Is there any way that I can explicitly place that datatype object in the dictionary?

Comment: What produces what? If you have a dict with the `str` type object in it, it will be output as `<class 'str'>` when you try to `print` it. That's still the `str` class though, that's just what it looks like when printed. It does that regardless of dicts or pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `'O'` to specify the column is `str` (or `Object` in `pandas` term):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """col1 col2
1 11
2 22
3 33
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep = "\s+", dtype={'col1': 'O', 'col2': int})
```

Output:

```
print(df)
  col1  col2
0    1    11
1    2    22
2    3    33

df.dtypes
col1    object
col2     int64
dtype: object

df['col1'].apply(lambda x:isinstance(x, str))
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` attribute of the class? ie `type(x).__name__` will give you the name of the class, which I think is what you want.

```
list_of_columns = ["a","b","c","d",1,1.1]
my_dict = {}
for column in list_of_columns:
    my_dict[column] = type(column).__name__  #or column.__class__.__name__
print(my_dict)
```

O/P:

```
{'a': 'str', 'b': 'str', 'c': 'str', 'd': 'str', 1: 'int', 1.1: 'float'}
```